# Google Drive SDK with Node.js googleapis package throws Error: Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts on files.create

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api

I'm trying to upload a file to Google Drive using their Api and Nodejs. I've successfully run the quickstart code found here:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs

I replaced the `metadata.readonly` scope in the example source with `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` and replaced the call to `listFiles()` with one I created, `createFile()`

```
function createFile(auth) {
    var service = google.drive('v3');
    service.files.create({
        auth: auth,
        resource: {
            name: 'test'
        },
        media: {
            mimeType: 'plain/text',
            body: 'Hello drive'
        },
        fields: 'id'
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('Resource created successfully: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    });
}
```

The response keeps coming back with en error:
`Error: Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.`

Would appreciate if anyone has some insight as to what is going wrong. Thanks!

Update: Downgrading from googleapis 25 to 24 seems to have resolved the issue.

Comment: Although I don't know whether this is a solution, I also had the same situation with you. When I use ``googleaps '25.0.0': '2018-01-20T02:19:03.432Z'``, the same error occurs. So I downgraded to ``'24.0.0': '2018-01-11T04:03:44.931Z'``. By this, it works fine. If this information was not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Downgrading to `24.0.0` seems to have resolved it. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Maintainer of the library here.  Problems like this tend to pop up if you are trying to install your own version of `google-auth-library` alongside of `googleapis`.  `googleapis` comes with a compatible version of `google-auth-library`.  Please make sure you remove `google-auth-library` from your package.json, and use `google.auth.OAuth2` to get a reference to your auth object.

Can you give this a try, and let me know if it works with version 27?