# Google Drive Upload API - Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-drive-api, drive

I am having a few issues with the Google Drive node.js library. I am trying to upload a picture to my google drive, I have authenticated previously hence the 'oauth2Client' object. This is taken nearly like for like from the [example](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads) on the google docs.

```
var service = googleApi.drive('v3');
var fileMetadata = {
    'name': 'jpeg-home.jpg'
};
var media = {
    mimeType: 'image/jpeg',
    body: fs.createReadStream('./temp/downloads/jpeg-home.jpg')
};
service.files.create({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    resource: fileMetadata,
    media: media,
    fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return false;
    } else {
        console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
        return true;
    }
});
```

The response I am getting is an error of:

```
Error: Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.
```

I have done some searching and couldn't find anything so any help would be appreciated. Cheers in advance.

Comment: Will this information be useful for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48492592/google-drive-sdk-with-node-js-googleapis-package-throws-error-invalid-multipart#comment83978644_48492592

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you sooner. Yes this did help thank you :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad your problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I'm the current maintainer of both `google-auth-library` and `googleapis`.  Please, *please* make sure that you do not install your own version of `google-auth-library` along side `googleapis`.  `googleapis` comes with a compatible version of `google-auth-library` built in.  If you try to install your own version - it could break in weird, unpredictable ways.

The right thing to do here is to delete `google-auth-library` from your package.json, run `npm install`, and then use `google.auth.OAuth2` for your requests.  Hope this helps!

Comment: i have the same issue in vue js, i have only googleapis in my package.json. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The samples in the docs https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-uploads appear to have been broken since version 25 of the googleapis package.

Reverting to googleapis@24.0.0 will resolve the problem until either the documentation or later package code is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by upgrading `google-auth-library` to latest version (1.3.2 at this moment).

In the official quickstart, it specifies to install the library like this:

`npm install google-auth-library@0.* --save`

Just do it like this to install the latest:

`npm install --save google-auth-library`

Notice that this upgrade has some breaking changes, so you need to upgrade your code of authorization like specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48934470/4725078)