# gmail API for sending users messages in nodejs javascript failes

Tags: gmail-api, google-api-nodejs-client, google-apis-explorer

My nodejs program fails to send messages using the Gmail api.

The solution from [Gmail API for sending mails in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546142/gmail-api-for-sending-mails-in-node-js) does not work for me.

I encode an email with

```
var {google} = require('googleapis');

// to and from = "some name <blaw.blaw.com"
function makeBody(to, from, subject, message) {
    var str = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\r\n",
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n",
        "to: ", to, "\r\n",
        "from: ", from, "\r\n",
        "subject: ", subject, "\r\n\r\n",
        message
    ].join('');

    encodedMail = new Buffer(str).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');  

    return encodedMail;
}
```

Then go to the Google API explorer
https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/
enter gmail.users.messages.send and the string generated from the above make_body.

[image]

An email will be successfully sent.  So I know the above encoding is 
ok.

When my program tried to send using the following, it fails with error

> Error: 'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via
>   /upload/* URL required

```
function sendMessage(auth) {
    var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
    var raw = makeBody('john g <asdfasdf@hotmail.com>', 'john g<asfasdgf@gmail.com>', 'test subject', 'test message #2');

    gmail.users.messages.send({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
        resource: {
            raw: raw
        }

    }, function(err, response) {
        console.log(err || response)
    });
}
```

The auth token is good since I can call gmail.users.labels.list and I use the same authorization when using the API explorer.

**Q1:** Does anyone know why the above does not work?

**Q2:** [Gmail API for sending mails in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34546142/gmail-api-for-sending-mails-in-node-js) does not explain why the raw email message is wrapped inside a resource field.  I tried simply raw and it did not help.

This fails.

```
gmail.users.messages.send({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
        resource: {
            raw: raw
        }

    }, function(err, response) {
        console.log(err || response)
    });
```

and so does

```
gmail.users.messages.send({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    raw: raw

}, function(err, response) {
    console.log(err || response)
});
```

and so does this [GMAIL API for sending Email with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784167/gmail-api-for-sending-email-with-attachment)

```
gmail.users.messages.send({
    auth: auth,
    userId: 'me',
    data: raw

}, function(err, response) {
    console.log(err || response)
});
```

Does anyone know where its documented how to pass the "requested body" the api explorer is asking for?

**Q3:** Why does the google api need substitutions in the base64 encoding?

I tried encoding using

```
const Base64 = require("js-base64").Base64
var encodedMail = Base64.encode(str);
```

When I feed this into the API explorer, I get the error

> "message": "Invalid value for ByteString:

Comment: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/send gives an example in the javascript tab but it says "Does not use a client library.".  But it does not say what it is using.  It makes a call gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.send but does not indicate what value gapi has.

Comment: Before going further, can you check if you can get some information in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590988/failed-sending-mail-through-google-api-with-javascript) and this another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26659744/sending-gmail-attachment-using-api-failed/26661866#26661866)?

Comment: Thank you for finding some more very similar issues. The first solution you found suggests using resource: raw:  is what I tried.  The second solution you found suggest multipart/related, but I'm trying to send a simple "hello world" no attachment and the content type works when I past the encoded string into the playground. This API is definitely could use some documentation and some examples for something that should be simple.

Comment: Like I said in the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72809574), you can refer to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579566/failed-sending-mail-through-google-api)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579566 appears to be a virtually identical problem, unsolved, and the author suggests not using googleapi API?  I did not see this one when I posted my problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48579566 It also does not ask the question Q2 (where does it say in documentation to wrap raw inside of resource). Maybe the documentation is lacking or I am not reading the correct documentation. Also, it does not ask Q3, why the substitution.

Answer (score 4):

Ohai! For others that stumble here, a few things.  First - we have a complete end to end sample of sending mail now here:

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/samples/gmail/send.js

Second, the answer above is mostly right :) Instead of installing the latest version of `google-auth-library`...  just remove it from your package.json all together.  The getting started guide was very, very wrong (it has since been fixed).  `googelapis` brings in it's own compatible version of `google-auth-library`, so you really don't want to mess with that by installing your own version :)

Answer (score 2):

The quickstart specifies:

```
npm install google-auth-library@0.* --save
```

When I changed this to

```
npm install google-auth-library -- save
```

it pulled in version 1.3.1 vs 0.12.0. Everything started working once I changed the code to account for the breaking changes.  The latest version of googleapis also has breaking changes. Here is my tweaks to the quickstart:

**package.json**

```
 ....
  "dependencies": {
    "google-auth-library": "^1.3.1",
    "googleapis": "^26.0.1"
  }
```

**quickstart.js**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var readline = require('readline');
var {google} = require('googleapis');
const {GoogleAuth, JWT, OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');


var SCOPES = [
    'https://mail.google.com/',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send'
];

var TOKEN_DIR = (process.env.HOME || process.env.HOMEPATH ||
    process.env.USERPROFILE) + '/.credentials/';
var TOKEN_PATH = TOKEN_DIR + 'gmail-nodejs-quickstart.json';

function authorize(credentials, callback) {
    var clientSecret = credentials.installed.client_secret;
    var clientId = credentials.installed.client_id;
    var redirectUrl = credentials.installed.redirect_uris[0];
    var auth = new GoogleAuth();
    var oauth2Client = new OAuth2Client(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);

    // Check if we have previously stored a token.
    fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, function (err, token) {
        if (err) {
            getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback);
        } else {
            oauth2Client.credentials = JSON.parse(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        }
    });
}

function getNewToken(oauth2Client, callback) {
    var authUrl = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
        access_type: 'offline',
        scope: SCOPES
    });
    console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url: ', authUrl);
    var rl = readline.createInterface({
        input: process.stdin,
        output: process.stdout
    });
    rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', function (code) {
        rl.close();
        oauth2Client.getToken(code, function (err, token) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error while trying to retrieve access token', err);
                return;
            }
            oauth2Client.credentials = token;
            storeToken(token);
            callback(oauth2Client);
        });
    });
}


function makeBody(to, from, subject, message) {
    var str = ["Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n",
        "MIME-Version: 1.0\n",
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n",
        "to: ", to, "\n",
        "from: ", from, "\n",
        "subject: ", subject, "\n\n",
        message
    ].join('');

    var encodedMail = new Buffer(str).toString("base64").replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');
        return encodedMail;
}

function sendMessage(auth) {
    var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
    var raw = makeBody('xxxxxxxx@hotmail.com', 'xxxxxxx@gmail.com', 'test subject', 'test message');
    gmail.users.messages.send({
        auth: auth,
        userId: 'me',
        resource: {
            raw: raw
        }
    }, function(err, response) {
        console.log(err || response)
    });
}

const secretlocation = 'client_secret.json'

fs.readFile(secretlocation, function processClientSecrets(err, content) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error loading client secret file: ' + err);
        return;
    }
    // Authorize a client with the loaded credentials, then call the
    // Gmail API.
    authorize(JSON.parse(content), sendMessage);
});
```

Now when I run, I get the response

```
Object {status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: Object, config: Object, request: ClientRequest, …}
```